# Create a self extracting file using VB.NET and DotNetZip or IonicZip Libraries

Tags: vb.net, file, dotnetzip, self-extracting

Well I'm very newbie with these libraries, where can I found information about the thing that I want to do?
Thanks :)

Comment: Without meaning to sound rude, their respective websites would be the obvious place :) [DotNetZip examples](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Okey, thanks. I don't know why the example that I see was in C++. ;)

Comment: Not sure but the VB ones in the link cover quite a few tasks depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I find the thing that I want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below have both VB and C# examples on extraction on execute:
http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedFileSystem/topic160.html